# Repeated Evaluation with Random Number Generation

Tags: julia

I have a function

```
function foo()
    return sum(rand([1,0], 5))
end
```

which is doing something including random number generation. How can I repeat the function call multiple times and store the results in an array. I know that I can do an array comprehension...

```
[foo() for i in 1:10]
```

but I have a feeling there must be something that works like `repeat()`, which you can use to fill arrays with the same value:

```
julia> repeat([4],3,4)

3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  4  4  4
 4  4  4  4
 4  4  4  4
```

Comment: I always use comprehension to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that an array comprehension is exactly the right thing here, and is what I would recommend. If you already have an array that you want to fill, you can use broadcasting with some nice syntax

```
julia> x = zeros(Int, 10);  # pre-allocated array

julia> x .= foo.()  # this works in-place
```

BTW, I would *not* recommend using the `repeat` function for filling arrays with numbers, it is not efficient, nor idiomatic. For filling an array, use `fill` (notice the name):

```
julia> fill(4, 3, 4)
3×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 4  4  4  4
 4  4  4  4
 4  4  4  4
```

I would also suggest a more efficient implementation of `foo`. It is not efficient to sample from a vector with `rand([0,1], 5)`. It is better to do

```
rand(0:1, 5)  # with a range
```

It is better still to use a tuple

```
rand((0, 1), 5)
```

And it is better *yet*, to sample booleans

```
rand(Bool, 5)
```

And if that weren't enough, there's no need to create all those vectors of 0s and 1s, or Bools, at all:

```
foo() = sum(rand(Bool) for _ in 1:5)
```

This function does not allocate any temporary array, and and will be much faster than your `foo`.

(And, just for fun, here's the fastest one I could find:

```
bar() = count_ones(rand(UInt8) & 0b00011111)
```

If the number of samples is max 64, then you can do this:

```
bar(N) = count_ones(rand(Int) & ((1 << N) - 1))
```

And for numbers > 64, you can loop it

```
function baz(N)
    (d, r) = divrem(N, 64)
    s = 0
    for i in 1:d
        s += count_ones(rand(Int))
    end
    return s + count_ones(rand(Int) & ((1 << r) - 1))
end
```

though, eventually, for very large N, around 20,000, it becomes faster to do `sum(bitrand(N))`
)

Though, for large N, one would probably want to use Distributions.jl with the Binomial distribution:

```
using Distributions

foo2(N) = rand(Binomial(N, 0.5))

julia> @btime foo2(20000000)
  28.056 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
9995529
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define `foo(x) = foo()` and use broadcasting to fill any array with multiple function calls to `foo()` like this:

```
foo.(zeros(4,4))
4×4 Matrix{Int64}:
 3  2  3  3
 5  2  4  3
 2  2  3  3
 3  3  3  3
```

And you can replace `zeros` here with any function that allocates an array of the required size. Note that this solution will not give any performance benefits compared to a comprehension, but you might prefer this form.

Note also that if you define the function `foo()` as

```
foo() = sum(rand(Bool, n))
```

with `n` greater than some small threshold, say 30, the function will be much faster because generating a bunch of `rand` numbers at once will be more efficient. If `n` is much larger, `sum(bitrand(n))` will be even better. Otherwise, try the funny tricks by @DNF for magical speeds.